# How do I uninstall xdebug on Debian?

Tags: linux, apache, zend-framework, debian

I have to use the Zend Optimizer. After 3 days I figured it doesn't get along with xdebug and now I want to uninstall it. How do I do that on Debian?

My server:

> PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Aug  4
>   2010 03:25:57)

Comment: Did you install xdebug with the debian package manager?

Comment: it's on the server. i don't recall using any package manager

Comment: Looks like it's generally installed via PECL, so you might want to try `sudo pecl uninstall xdebug`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed the binary (search for xdebug.so) and then removed all
zend_extension= lines from php.ini regarding Xdebug and now everything works.